# Cannot log in with any user

Tags: login, 16.04

When I try to log in to my account from the GUI the screen becames black and after a short time the log in screen reappears. This happens if I try to log in as guest as well. However, I manage to log in from the shell (which I enter with CTRl+ALT+F1). I attach some information:

During my last session I edited a bunch of files in order to change the default path of .Xauthority, .xsession-errors and .xsession-errors.old, and to remove the file .sudo_as_admin_successful from my home… but I stupidly did not take notes of what I did. I have Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I can remember I edited the following files:
/etc/group
/etc/bash.bashrc *
/etc/rc.local *
/etx/X11/[something]

(*: I have undone the editing of this file)

And the following variable:
$XAUTHORITY

It is very likely I forgot something.
Now I experience the following:
I cannot find the .xsession-errors files
I cannot find the variable $XAUTHORITY
The file .Xauthority belongs to me, not root
The file .Xauthority contains a strange line which I do not understand: ^A^@^@^Ofederico-laptop^@^AO^@^RMIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1^@^P and then some diamonds…

(Sorry if I cannot copy the line, but I only have that laptop and I am writing from my smartphone.)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest, use a live CD to access all of your data and back them up onto external storage.

You can back up the Home folder hidden files too, this contains application settings, especially look at the .config folder.

To display hidden files, navigate to the folder you want to look and and use 'CTRL H'

Then I would suggest a fresh install. Once installed reinstall your applications and copy back the appropiate .config files, etc.

OR

You could try to start up an Ubuntu live CD session in order to undo the changes?

Use the terminal command

Code:

```
sudo nautilus
```

and navigate to your Linux partition, and attempt to reset the changes using the live disk as a reference.

Some info [HERE](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery)

Comment: OK, was going with the fresh installation, but now I have a much serious problem… I think I will write a new post. Thank you for your answer.